WebRTC connection does not happen after ICE exchange
This is an issue that has been bugging me for a whole week.....
I am trying to establish a webRTC connection with a python server using aiortc/ web client. Both client and server is connected within a local network with no firewall.
I have exchanged SDP/ICE messages through ROS, and confirmed that the messages contain local addresses of both machines. (For those who are not familiar to ros, it is a sub/pub messaging protocol used in robotics)
The connection fails and the video feed is not shown, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be truly appreciated :)
Client Code
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useROS } from './ROSContext';
import ROSLIB from 'roslib';

const WebRTCClient: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const peerConnection = useRef<RTCPeerConnection | null>(null);
  const { ros } = useROS();

  useEffect(() => {
    const configuration: RTCConfiguration = {
      iceTransportPolicy: 'all', // TypeScript should accept 'all' here
      iceServers: [] // No STUN or TURN servers needed for your local network
    };
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    peerConnection.current = pc;

    pc.addTransceiver('video');

    // Display the incoming video stream
    pc.ontrack = (event) => {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        videoRef.current.srcObject = event.streams[0];
        console.log(event.streams[0]);
        videoRef.current.play().then(() => {
          console.log('Video playback started');
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error starting video playback:', error);
        })
      }
    };

    pc.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
      console.log('Connection state changed:', pc.connectionState);
    }

    pc.onicecandidateerror = (event) => {
      console.error('ICE candidate error:', event);
    };

    pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      console.log('Negotiation needed');
    };

    pc.onicegatheringstatechange = () => {
      console.log('ICE gathering state changed:', pc.iceGatheringState);
    }

    pc.ondatachannel = (event) => {
      console.log('Data channel created:', event.channel);
    }

    pc.onsignalingstatechange = () => {
      console.log('Signaling state changed:', pc.signalingState);
    }

    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
      console.log('ICE connection state changed:', pc.iceConnectionState);
    }

    // Publish ICE candidates to the ROS node
    const candidatePublishTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
      ros: ros,
      name: '/webrtc_ice_candidate_client',
      messageType: 'webrtc_services/ICECandidate',
    });

    pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        const candidateMsg = {
          component: event.candidate.component,
          foundation: event.candidate.foundation,
          address: event.candidate.address,
          port: event.candidate.port,
          priority: event.candidate.priority,
          protocol: event.candidate.protocol,
          type: event.candidate.type,
          sdpmid: event.candidate.sdpMid,
          sdpmlineindex: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
        }
        // print all parameters
        console.log('ICE candidate:', candidateMsg);
        candidatePublishTopic.publish(new ROSLIB.Message(candidateMsg));
      }
    };

    // Subscribe to ICE candidates from ROS node
    const candidateSubscribeTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
      ros: ros,
      name: '/webrtc_ice_candidate_server',
      messageType: 'webrtc_services/ICECandidate',
    });

    candidateSubscribeTopic.subscribe((message) => {
      const candidateData = JSON.parse(message.data);
      const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
        candidate: candidateData.candidate,
        sdpMid: candidateData.sdpMid,
        sdpMLineIndex: candidateData.sdpMLineIndex,
      });
      console.log('Received ICE candidate:', candidate);
      pc.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(console.error);
    });

    // Handle SDP offer/answer with ROS
    pc.createOffer({ offerToReceiveVideo: true })
      .then((offer) => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
      .then(() => {
        const webrtcOfferService = new ROSLIB.Service({
          ros: ros,
          name: '/webrtc_sdp_offer',
          serviceType: 'webrtc_services/SDPExchange',
        });

        webrtcOfferService.callService(
          new ROSLIB.ServiceRequest({
            sdp: pc.localDescription.sdp,
            type: pc.localDescription.type,
          }),
          (response) => {
            const answer = new RTCSessionDescription({
              sdp: response.sdp,
              type: response.type,
            });

            console.log('Received SDP answer:', answer);
            pc.setRemoteDescription(answer)
              .then(() => {
                console.log('Remote description set');
              });
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(console.error);

    return () => {
      if (peerConnection.current) {
        peerConnection.current.close();
        candidateSubscribeTopic.unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  }, [ros]);

  return (
    <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay playsInline style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} />
  );
};

export default WebRTCClient;


Server Code
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile, QoSDurabilityPolicy, QoSReliabilityPolicy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from webrtc_services.srv import SDPExchange
from webrtc_services.msg import ICECandidate
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCIceCandidate, RTCSessionDescription, VideoStreamTrack
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import asyncio
import json
import cv2

class CameraStreamTrack(VideoStreamTrack):
    def __init__(self, node):
        super().__init__()
        self.node = node
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

    async def recv(self):
        pts, time_base = await self.next_timestamp()
        frame = self.node.get_frame()
        self.node.get_logging("recording frames")
        if frame is not None:
            return frame

class WebRTCNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('webrtc_node')

        # Publisher and subscriber for ICE candidates
        self.ice_candidate_pub = self.create_publisher(ICECandidate, '/webrtc_ice_candidate_server', 10)
        self.ice_candidate_sub = self.create_subscription(
            ICECandidate,
            '/webrtc_ice_candidate_client',
            self.handle_remote_ice_candidate,
            10
        )

        # ROS service for SDP exchange
        self.create_service(SDPExchange, '/webrtc_sdp_offer', self.handle_offer)

        # Subscription to the image topic
        self.image_sub = self.create_subscription(Image, '/camera/image', self.image_callback, 10)
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.frame = None
        self.pc = None

    def image_callback(self, msg):
        # Convert the ROS image message to an OpenCV image and store it
        self.frame = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")

    def get_frame(self):
        # Convert OpenCV image to a WebRTC-compatible frame
        if self.frame is None:
            return None
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return VideoFrame.from_ndarray(frame_rgb, format="rgb24")

    def handle_offer(self, request, response):
        self.get_logger().info(f"Received SDP offer: {request}")

        response = asyncio.run(self.sync_handle_offer(request, response))

        self.get_logger().info(f"Sending SDP answer: {response}")

        return response

    async def sync_handle_offer(self, request, response):
        self.pc = RTCPeerConnection()
        # Debugging ICE state changes

        @self.pc.on("icegatheringstatechange")
        def in_icegatheringstatechange():
            print(f"ICE Gathering State: {self.pc.iceGatheringState}")

        @self.pc.on("icecandidate")
        def on_icecandidate(event):
            self.send_ice_candidate(event)

        @self.pc.on("connectionstatechange")
        async def on_connectionstatechange():
            self.get_logger().info(f"Connection state is {pc.connectionState}")
            if self.pc.connectionState == "failed":
                await self.pc.close()

        self.pc.addTrack(CameraStreamTrack(self))
        await self.pc.setRemoteDescription(RTCSessionDescription(sdp=request.sdp, type=request.type))
        answer = await self.pc.createAnswer()
        await self.pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
        response.sdp = self.pc.localDescription.sdp
        response.type = self.pc.localDescription.type
        return response
    def send_ice_candidate(self, event):
        self.get_logger().info(f"Sent ICE candidate: {event.candidate}")
        if event.candidate:
            candidate_msg = {
                'component': event.candidate.component,
                'foundation': event.candidate.founndation,
                'address': event.candidate.ip,
                'sdpMid': event.candidate.sdpMid,
                'sdpMLineIndex': event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex
            }
            self.ice_candidate_pub.publish(candidate_msg)

    def handle_remote_ice_candidate(self, msg):
        candidate = RTCIceCandidate(
            ip=msg.address,
            component=msg.component,
            foundation=msg.foundation,
            port=msg.port,
            priority=msg.priority,
            protocol=msg.protocol,
            type=msg.type,
            sdpMid=msg.sdpmid,
            sdpMLineIndex=msg.sdpmlineindex

        )

        self.get_logger().info(f"Adding remote ICE candidate: {candidate}")
        asyncio.run(self.pc.addIceCandidate(candidate))

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = WebRTCNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Here are the detailed connection detail:
Web Connection Log:
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::RTCPeerConnection(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) 
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::initializeConfiguration(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) 
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::addTransceiver(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) 
[Log] MediaStreamTrackPrivate::MediaStreamTrackPrivate(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) 
[Log] RealtimeIncomingVideoSource::setLogger(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) Video, remote video, , 
[Log] MediaStreamTrack::MediaStreamTrack(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) 
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::createOffer(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) 
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::setLocalDescription(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) Setting local description to:
v=0
o=- 7782012141166886532 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 127 125 112 113 114
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:KQRm
a=ice-pwd:q8ENF12PK1LdBjpOjL4e2Skg
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 96:74:04:42:50:DF:8E:A0:6D:C4:86:B8:37:26:22:70:61:5F:63:E3:4A:B9:9C:16:D1:C4:2E:DF:97:76:91:88
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:4 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:- 9c5a3581-0b2f-4d66-834f-5139cfa5a44f
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640c1f
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=640c1f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:103 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:103 apt=102
a=rtpmap:104 H265/90000
a=rtcp-fb:104 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:104 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:104 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:104 nack
a=rtcp-fb:104 nack pli
a=rtpmap:105 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:105 apt=104
a=rtpmap:106 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:106 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:106 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:106 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack pli
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=106
a=rtpmap:108 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:127 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:125 apt=127
a=rtpmap:112 red/90000
a=rtpmap:113 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:113 apt=112
a=rtpmap:114 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 1685303567 3271658131
a=ssrc:1685303567 cname:Z709ambahT0RDel0
a=ssrc:1685303567 msid:- 9c5a3581-0b2f-4d66-834f-5139cfa5a44f
a=ssrc:3271658131 cname:Z709ambahT0RDel0
a=ssrc:3271658131 msid:- 9c5a3581-0b2f-4d66-834f-5139cfa5a44f

[Log] PeerConnectionBackend::setLocalDescriptionSucceeded(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) 
[Log] Signaling state changed: – "have-local-offer" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 63)
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::setSignalingState(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) have-local-offer
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'signalingstatechange'
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::updateIceGatheringState(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) gathering
[Log] ICE gathering state changed: – "gathering" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 57)
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'icegatheringstatechange'
[Log] ICE candidate: – {component: "rtp", foundation: "3393445816", address: "4a67bbe8-d708-43f7-94e3-ea82ffb95089.local", …} (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 86)
{component: "rtp", foundation: "3393445816", address: "4a67bbe8-d708-43f7-94e3-ea82ffb95089.local", port: 62974, priority: 2122260223, …}Object
[Log] PeerConnectionBackend::newICECandidate(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) Gathered ice candidate:candidate:3393445816 1 udp 2122260223 4a67bbe8-d708-43f7-94e3-ea82ffb95089.local 62974 typ host generation 0 ufrag KQRm network-id 1 network-cost 50
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'icecandidate'
[Log] Received SDP answer: – RTCSessionDescription {type: "answer", sdp: "v=0\r↵o=- 3940639792 3940639792 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r↵s=-…0:1A:7E:09:F8:50:19:8A:B0:2D:5C\r↵a=setup:active\r↵", toJSON: function} (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 121)
RTCSessionDescription {type: "answer", sdp: "v=0\r↵o=- 3940639792 3940639792 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r↵s=-…0:1A:7E:09:F8:50:19:8A:B0:2D:5C\r↵a=setup:active\r↵", toJSON: function}RTCSessionDescription
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::setRemoteDescription(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) Setting remote description to:
v=0
o=- 3940639792 3940639792 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=video 58412 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98 99 106 107
c=IN IP4 192.168.0.20
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=mid:0
a=msid:7dec0f4c-dccc-44f0-aa0a-4c2d1671cc1a acf20468-57dc-4ae7-b6ad-e4686c658e19
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=ssrc-group:FID 3559455750 2867110572
a=ssrc:3559455750 cname:f11e3cba-8069-4a9a-a276-1f15fbfb4c5b
a=ssrc:2867110572 cname:f11e3cba-8069-4a9a-a276-1f15fbfb4c5b
a=rtpmap:98 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=fmtp:98 packetization-mode=1;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:106 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:106 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=106
a=candidate:4f322c660417b6096fd16770d34b336f 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.0.20 58412 typ host
a=candidate:bf734b071273f7d6ccf572c7ec2b884c 1 udp 2130706431 100.109.42.26 51514 typ host
a=candidate:cfde7b013ffc28500306e12b2dfcc5df 1 udp 2130706431 fd7a:115c:a1e0::4701:2a1a 34958 typ host
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-ufrag:qpYE
a=ice-pwd:U5kNWMQLZBpmlO7X3Cl9aK
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F9:BD:7F:81:A7:4A:91:FC:F2:A3:52:6A:68:7E:45:AD:E5:1C:46:60:BE:80:1A:7E:09:F8:50:19:8A:B0:2D:5C
a=setup:active

[Log] ICE connection state changed: – "checking" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 66)
[Log] Connection state changed: – "connecting" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 48)
[Log] MediaStream::MediaStream(4957DBA2058B65BF) 
[Log] PeerConnectionBackend::setRemoteDescriptionSucceeded(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) Set remote description succeeded
[Log] Signaling state changed: – "stable" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 63)
[Log] MediaStream {id: "7dec0f4c-dccc-44f0-aa0a-4c2d1671cc1a", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, getAudioTracks: function, …} (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 39)
[Log] Remote description set (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 123)
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'iceconnectionstatechange'
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'connectionstatechange'
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::setSignalingState(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) stable
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'signalingstatechange'
[Log] MediaStream::addTrackFromPlatform(4957DBA2058B65BF) (BA8E06A6504A3BD3)
[Log] MediaStream::setIsActive(4957DBA2058B65BF) true
[Log] MediaStreamPrivate::addTrack(4957DBA2058B65BF) (BA8E06A6504A3BD3)
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'track'
[Log] RealtimeIncomingVideoSource::setMuted(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) false
[Log] RealtimeIncomingVideoSource::start(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) 
[Log] MediaStreamTrackPrivate::sourceStarted(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) 
[Log] MediaStreamTrack::trackStarted(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) 
[Log] MediaStreamPrivate::trackStarted(4957DBA2058B65BF) (BA8E06A6504A3BD3)
[Log] MediaStreamTrackPrivate::sourceMutedChanged(BA8E06A6504A3BD3) 
[Log] MediaStreamPrivate::trackMutedChanged(4957DBA2058B65BF) (BA8E06A6504A3BD3) false
[Log] ICE candidate: – {component: "rtp", foundation: "887687980", address: "4a67bbe8-d708-43f7-94e3-ea82ffb95089.local", …} (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 86)
{component: "rtp", foundation: "887687980", address: "4a67bbe8-d708-43f7-94e3-ea82ffb95089.local", port: 9, priority: 1518280447, …}Object
[Log] PeerConnectionBackend::newICECandidate(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) Gathered ice candidate:candidate:887687980 1 tcp 1518280447 4a67bbe8-d708-43f7-94e3-ea82ffb95089.local 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag KQRm network-id 1 network-cost 50
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'icecandidate'
[Log] PeerConnectionBackend::doneGatheringCandidates(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) Finished ice candidate gathering
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::updateIceGatheringState(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) complete
[Log] ICE gathering state changed: – "complete" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 57)
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'icecandidate'
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'icegatheringstatechange'
[Log] RTCPeerConnection::~RTCPeerConnection(338101729BB856C6) 
[Log] MediaStreamTrackPrivate::~MediaStreamTrackPrivate(4D28631C76C5CFBA) 
[Error] Error starting video playback: – AbortError: The operation was aborted.
AbortError: The operation was aborted.
    (anonymous function) (WebRTCClient.tsx:43)
[Log] ICE connection state changed: – "failed" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 66)
[Log] Connection state changed: – "failed" (WebRTCClient.tsx, line 48)
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'iceconnectionstatechange'
[Info] RTCPeerConnection::dispatchEvent(1E94BA3545EC2ECF) dispatching 'connectionstatechange'

Python Log:
[INFO] [1731651122.769201987] [webrtc_node]: Received SDP offer: webrtc_services.srv.SDPExchange_Request(sdp='v=0\r\no=- 3412801876427003791 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 127 125 112 113 114\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:riId\r\na=ice-pwd:jI71cRZ+Sxl0x36PmJbndf02\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 97:AD:D7:E4:A9:8A:CC:D2:79:E2:24:B0:F3:2E:DF:59:EA:B6:50:04:C3:53:94:CB:A9:57:B0:27:4E:13:8C:D3\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing\r\na=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space\r\na=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id\r\na=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:- 1b95d910-2910-49e4-a9ac-50cbce42d3cd\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640c1f\r\na=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\na=rtpmap:98 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:98 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:100 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=640c1f\r\na=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\na=rtpmap:102 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:103 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:103 apt=102\r\na=rtpmap:104 H265/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:104 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:104 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:104 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:104 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:104 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:104 level-id=93;tx-mode=SRST\r\na=rtpmap:105 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:105 apt=104\r\na=rtpmap:106 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:107 apt=106\r\na=rtpmap:108 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:108 profile-id=0\r\na=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:109 apt=108\r\na=rtpmap:127 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:127 profile-id=2\r\na=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:125 apt=127\r\na=rtpmap:112 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:113 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:113 apt=112\r\na=rtpmap:114 ulpfec/90000\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 3286714346 12295951\r\na=ssrc:3286714346 cname:dShL10ZK1y3XGZJD\r\na=ssrc:3286714346 msid:- 1b95d910-2910-49e4-a9ac-50cbce42d3cd\r\na=ssrc:12295951 cname:dShL10ZK1y3XGZJD\r\na=ssrc:12295951 msid:- 1b95d910-2910-49e4-a9ac-50cbce42d3cd\r\n', type='offer')
ICE Gathering State: gathering
ICE Gathering State: complete
[INFO] [1731651122.789813194] [webrtc_node]: Sending SDP answer: webrtc_services.srv.SDPExchange_Response(sdp='v=0\r\no=- 3940639922 3940639922 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=video 44236 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98 99 106 107\r\nc=IN IP4 192.168.0.20\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=mid:0\r\na=msid:c98bd3b6-403c-4993-b56f-e4a9011b4ff9 60f6ea3e-5120-4d21-9130-9d50aadcc351\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 1478075735 713819296\r\na=ssrc:1478075735 cname:9aa688cf-caad-4e7e-a604-7a23eb7c68d6\r\na=ssrc:713819296 cname:9aa688cf-caad-4e7e-a604-7a23eb7c68d6\r\na=rtpmap:98 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=fmtp:98 packetization-mode=1;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:106 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:106 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:107 apt=106\r\na=candidate:4f322c660417b6096fd16770d34b336f 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.0.20 44236 typ host\r\na=candidate:bf734b071273f7d6ccf572c7ec2b884c 1 udp 2130706431 100.109.42.26 43464 typ host\r\na=candidate:cfde7b013ffc28500306e12b2dfcc5df 1 udp 2130706431 fd7a:115c:a1e0::4701:2a1a 38730 typ host\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ice-ufrag:E7sT\r\na=ice-pwd:JCrFGjTr4LJmFM6VConLbC\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 0D:44:B0:D7:40:CC:79:E2:4A:51:E4:68:45:05:7B:B7:4C:D8:F4:15:AA:47:A0:00:72:FC:60:51:58:0F:B5:5A\r\na=setup:active\r\n', type='answer')
[INFO] [1731651122.794763206] [webrtc_node]: Adding remote ICE candidate: RTCIceCandidate(component='rtp', foundation='3240994852', ip='6f5ad9e3-e8c7-42a2-96e2-c416ccefca6d.local', port=64917, priority=2122260223, protocol='udp', type='host', relatedAddress=None, relatedPort=None, sdpMid='0', sdpMLineIndex=0, tcpType=None)
[INFO] [1731651123.799837717] [webrtc_node]: Adding remote ICE candidate: RTCIceCandidate(component='rtp', foundation='1065843888', ip='6f5ad9e3-e8c7-42a2-96e2-c416ccefca6d.local', port=9, priority=1518280447, protocol='tcp', type='host', relatedAddress=None, relatedPort=None, sdpMid='0', sdpMLineIndex=0, tcpType=None)


Are you sure you want to implement this from scratch? It's hard enough when you use a library. How many robots do you want to run this on, and will this need to work over unreliable network connections? Do you need hardware accelerated encoding?

I certainly have the option to stream mjpeg/vp8 videos with web_video_server, but this involves more latency and unstable connection. webrtc_ros is a no-go because it doesn't support ubuntu 22.04. I have to teleoperate a robot from a mile away using a 2.4 Ghz PTP connection, and the network quality will fluctuate a lot. It will only serve one client, so hardware accelerated encoding isn't an issue.

Makes sense. You might find this blog post of mine interesting: https://transitiverobotics.com/blog/streaming-video-from-robots/
